# how to add a node attribute using cytoscape java api?

Tags: java, api, cytoscape

I'm trying to do a cytoscape app using the java API, so, based on the example in [cytoscape github (sample create network)](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape-app-samples/tree/master/sample-create-network/src/main/java/org/cytoscape/sample/internal) I'm doing something like

```
    // Create an empty network
    CyNetwork myNet = cnf.createNetwork();
    myNet.getRow(myNet).set(CyNetwork.NAME,
                  namingUtil.getSuggestedNetworkTitle("My Network"));

    // Add two nodes to the network
    CyNode node1 = myNet.addNode();
    CyNode node2 = myNet.addNode();

    // set name for new nodes
    myNet.getDefaultNodeTable().getRow(node1.getSUID()).set("name", "Node1");
    myNet.getDefaultNodeTable().getRow(node2.getSUID()).set("name", "Node2");

    // Add an edge
    myNet.addEdge(node1, node2, true);
```

But, when I tried to do something like

```
    myNet.getDefaultNodeTable().getRow(node1.getSUID()).set("name", "Node1");
    myNet.getDefaultNodeTable().getRow(node1.getSUID()).set("symbol", "other string");
```

I get an error saying "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'symbol' does not yet exist"

So, anyone could guide me to correctly add an attribute to the nodes?

Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create the column as follow

```
myNet.getDefaultNodeTable().createColumn("symbol", String.class, false);
```